# Not able to send mails from the WHM hosted on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, port, cpanel, whm

I set up a WHM server on AWS EC2 instance and configured it to host a site. I also planned to use the WHM email service to send and receive mails but found that the emails were received on those email users created in WHM but were not able to send the emails.

Is there any way to send emails from the WHM server without using AWS SES or other email relay services?

Comment: If you have a valid plan for preventing spam from being sent, you can request port 25 be unblocked. FYI SES supports sending as an SMTP relay, you do not need to use the SES API. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-port-25-throttle/

Comment: Seems I have do the same